# How to subtract the number of the wc -l output in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want the output to filter out the number of specific lines in a file, so I count both the content that I need and I don't need and do subtraction. But somehow the output is not changing.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$1"/*;
do
    cat "$file" | while read line;
do
    countContent1="$(grep '\(<Content>\)' | wc -l)"
    countContent2="$(grep '\(showReview\)' | wc -l)"
    valuableReviews="$(($countContent1-$countContent2))"
    echo "$(b=${file##*/}; echo ${b%.*})" $valuableReviews
done
done | sort -r -n -k 2
```

note that both `<content>` and `showReview` are on the same line in the file. The output is only the number of the line contain `<content>`, there's no subtraction.

Here is part of the file:

```
<Author>lass=
<Content>Empfehlenswert....   showReview(11348491, 'full');  
<Date>Sep 28, 2006
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>4
<Value>-1
<Rooms>4
<Location>-1
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>-1
<Service>4
<Business service>-1
```

Comment: It is because no lines matched `\(showReview\)`. Please include the part of the file that you want to match in your question if you need help with the regex.

Comment: @sergio There is because if I only do `echo $countContent2` it works...

Comment: Why in the world would you run multiple copies of grep for each line of input?

Comment: @Charles Duffy Sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: When you run `countContent1="$(grep '\(<Content>\)' | wc -l)"`, `grep` reads *all the input on stdin*. When it finishes, there's thus no input left on stdin for `grep '\(showReview\)'`, or for the next `read line` command to see.

Comment: And running external commands is *slow*. If what you meant to do was `grep '[<]Content[>]' <<<"$line"`, searching only in the individual line, it would be much faster to replace it with, say, `case $line in "<Content>"*) ...handle line with content here...;; "<Date>"*) ...handle line with date here...;; esac`

Comment: @Charles Duffy Should I use `sed` instead?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), *How do I do string manipulations in bash?*, for guidance on better practices for search for or extract substrings.

Comment: `sed` is still an external command, and so still slow to start. To be clear, external commands are often faster than built-in bash code *after they've started up*, but the cost to start them up is high, so you want to run just one copy for *all* your data, not run a new copy (or, worse, multiple new copies) for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes more sense if you take out the inner `while read` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$1"/*; do
    countContent1=$(grep -c '[<]Content[>]' <"$file")
    countContent2=$(grep -c 'showReview' <"$file")
    valuableReviews=$((countContent1 - countContent2))
    b=${file##*/}; b=${b%.*}
    echo "$b $valuableReviews"
done | sort -r -n -k 2
```

Note:

- We're redirecting `"$file"` into each copy of `grep`, so grep is counting content *in the file* instead of content *on stdin*.
- We've removed the `while read` loop entirely, and are letting `grep` iterate over the individual lines of each file, rather than trying to do that in bash. (Consequently, we now run grep twice *per file*, not twice *per line of each file*).
- We aren't using command substitutions unnecessarily. `$(...)` has a significant performance penalty (lower than running an external command, but still much higher than doing everything in the parent process).

---

It would be still faster to replace the entire program with just *one* copy of awk:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

/[<]Content[>]/ {
  ++allContent
  if ($0 ~ /showReview/) {
    ++valuableReviews
  }
}
FILENAME != fn {
  if(fn) { print(fn, ": ", (allContent - valuableReviews)); }
  allContent = 0; valuableReviews = 0; fn = FILENAME;
}
END {
  print(fn, ": ", (allContent - valuableReviews))
}
```

...called as `./theAwkScript "$1"/*`

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it now!

Answer (score 0):

```
    :>cat file1.txt
    <Author>lass=
    <Content>Empfehlenswert....   showReview(11348491, 'full');
    <Date>Sep 28, 2006
    <No. Reader>-1
    <No. Helpful>-1
    <Overall>4
    <Value>-1
    <Rooms>4
    <Location>-1
    <Cleanliness>5
    <Check in / front desk>-1
    <Service>4
    <Business service>-1

    :>echo -e  "Lines with content $(grep -c Content file1.txt)\nLines with showReview $(grep -c showReview file1.txt)"
    Lines with content 1
    Lines with showReview 1
    :>
```

```
grep -c Content file1.txt -- Count of lines matching pattern 
$() --> Run some command
```